# Trying to calculate autocorrelation coefficient with function

Tags: python, function, numpy, time-series, autocorrelation

I am trying to replicate this autocorrelation formula, where `T` is number of samples and `k` is number of lags.

[image: Autocorrelation formula]

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: there's quite a lot wrong here, 1) your use of `np.sum` is not doing what you think it is, 2) whenever `i == 2` your 'demoninator == 0` which will throw a `nan` when you divide by `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocorrelation for the first element is 1.0 per definition. For the remaining elements we use a list comprehension (please note that the formula in the questions assumes indexing from 1 to T whereas python arrays are 0 based):

```
mean = np.mean(x)    
denominator = np.sum((x-mean)**2)
[1.0] + [np.sum((x[j:]-mean) * (x[:-j]-mean)) / denominator for j in range(1, len(x))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stef! May I ask what the `[1.0]` stands for? What's its purpose?

Comment: The 1.0 is the first element in the list, i.e the autocorrelation with `lag = 0`. When you solve the formula you gave in your question for k = 0 you'll see that your get 1.0.

Comment: I see... But why are you including it outside the loop?

Comment: It's just a technical difficulty: for j = 0 the second slice (`x[:-j]`) becomes `x[:-0]` which is an empty array because python makes no difference between `x[:0]` (up to not including 0th element) and `x[:-0]` which we need to be interpreted as up to 0th element from the end (= the whole array) but python treats it as `x[:0]`. Therefore we set the first element to the a priori known value of 1.0 instead of calcutating it.